# somar os valores do banco de dados e exibir o resultado no template flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, tabela-banco-de-dados, flask, sqlalchemy

tenho ma tabela com seguintes informações:

```
class Registro(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
valores = db.Column(db.Float)

------------|
  valores   |
------------|
   1.50     |
------------|
   2.40     |
------------|
   3.55     |
------------

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
va = Registro.query.all()
def index():
return render_template('index.html', va=va)
```

queria fazer a soma desse valores e mostra o resultado no template. Como seria a lógica para conseguir esse resultado usando flask-sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

@app.route('/')
def index():
    va = Registro.query(func.sum(Registro.valores)).all()
    return render_template('index.html', va=va)
```

no arquivo index.html

```
{{va}}
```

Comment: obrigado Carlos resolvi com a sua ajuda

Comment: Que bom que pude contribuir.

Comment: Carlos não querendo abusa da sua paciência pois com a sua ajuda conseguir resolver a minha duvida mas surgiu outra. 
Fiz o mesmo procedimento numa tabela que contem horas em float  que resultado total dessa soma foi  14.75 que é 14:47:24. O senhor conhece alguma instrução sqlalchemy que pode resolver essa conversão FLOAT para hora no formato "HH:MM" ?